# How to wrap text android listview

Tags: android, android-layout

http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/9858/howtowrapmiddletext.png

Basically I have a listview that is split in three sections. On the left is an image, the right is a button, and the middle is text that I want wrapped. See my picture for what I'm talking about

Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_drink_selected"
    android:id="@+id/img1"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here are a few things you can try:

1) Do you have `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your linearlayout?

2) for your EditText, set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

if that doesn't work,
3) for your EditText, set `android:layout_width="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Just do #1.  #2 shouldn't matter.  Also, add layout_weight="1" to the TextView, in case the text is less than the full width.  Along the same lines, I'd suggest making the left image an exact dimension, so you don't get weird alignment.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it working by setting LinearLayout `android:orientation="horizontal` and adding `layout_weight="1"` in the TextView. This was the key combination.